# Do FastReport VCL 5 needs to be installed on client before its use?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl, fastreport

I prefer to use **Delphi 7** to build windows applications because it doesn't require the clients to have additional installation of things like JDK, .NET Framework and etcetera.

If I deploy my application with a report using **FastReport VCL 5**, do the client needs to install first the **FastReport VCL 5**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Fast Report VCL is a part of your application exe.